# Error in my open-cart website

Tags: php, opencart

I have an open-cart 1.5.6.4 in which have installed Eclipse - Premium Responsive Open-cart Theme on it.Its working fine.But when I completed the theme installation.I got an error at the top of store front page or home page of my website.Error is like this:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in G:\PleskVhosts\mydomain.com\marketplace.mydomain.com\catalog\controller\module\category_product_slider.php
>   on line 79Notice: Undefined index: name in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\mydomain.com\marketplace.mydomain.com\catalog\controller\module\category_product_slider.php
>   on line 139

Line 139:

```
$this->data['category_name2'] = $category_result2['name'];
```

I am new to open-cart.Any help would be strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error said, you have in ´G:\PleskVhosts\mydomain.com\marketplace.mydomain.com\catalog\controller\module\category_product_slider.php on line 79Notice: Undefined index: name in G:\PleskVhosts\mydomain.com\marketplace.mydomain.com\catalog\controller\module\category_product_slider.php´

on line 139, something like:

```
if($_GET[´name´]) ......
```

but you have to check first if it is set with:

```
if(isset($_GET[´name´])) .....
```

If this not work, maybe you can post that particular line so i we can help you.

Comment: thx @ D3F but Not working this is the line   :                                     $this->data['category_name2'] = $category_result2['name'];

Comment: the line should be: $this->data['category_name2'] = (isset($category_result2['name'])?$category_result2['name']:'');